# Autoincrement keys using DataMapper with legacy PostgreSQL db

Tags: ruby, postgresql, doctrine, datamapper

I have an existing PostgreSQL database that I want to access with Ruby DataMapper. I have created my models according to the existing database schemata, but primary keys are not auto incremented.

My models look like this:

```
class Company
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end
```

Defining the `id` as `Serial` has no effect: when I create an instance I get an `DataObjects::IntegrityError` because of a violated not-null constraint.

The database is shared with a PHP/Doctrine application, so I cannot change the schema. The PHP application uses a sequence to create the primary keys like this:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('"production"."sequence_id_seq"') 
INSERT INTO "production"."companies" ("name", "id") VALUES ('Acme Inc.', 40711)
```

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE production.companies
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT companies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

This is the equivalent Doctrine schema definition:

```
CompanyOrm:
  tableName: companies
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      unsigned: 1
      primary: true
      sequence: sequence_id
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
```

How can I recreate that behavior with DataMapper? Or what other (better) solutions exist to create auto incrementing keys in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nextval()` function in an expression to fetch and use the next sequence value as the `id`:

```
INSERT INTO "production"."companies" ("name", "id") 
VALUES ('Acme Inc.', nextval('production.sequence_id_seq') )
```

I don't know enough about DataMapper to say whether or not it's possible to cause a function to be used in an INSERT, but maybe there's some way to do it by defining your own [Datamapper::Property](http://datamapper.org/docs/properties) (instead of Serial)?

Alternatively, you could alter the table to make the row default to using the sequence, which shouldn't break compatibility with anything that manually uses the same sequence:

```
ALTER TABLE production.companies 
  ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('production.sequence_id_seq');
```